# Unwanted vertical white space between Table and caption in LYX

Tags: tables, lyx, captions

I'm using LYX. I am placing figures and tables in floats and using a minibox to provide the captions for each.

However, in some cases there is a big white space between the table and its caption. Can I somehow decrease it or remove? How can I control the distance between the caption and figures/ tables in LYX?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might work is the `\vspace{-1in}` command before the minibox that holds the caption but after you make the float.

If that doesn't work, try placing the `\vspace{}` command inside the minibox declaration. That being said, I'm not familiar with LyX and it seems like the graphical interface they provide might prevent you from doing this easily.